# Determine JDBC fetchSize on an a packaged based web application

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a particularly tricky situation here. I am supporting an java based packaged web application that runs on JBoss. The application is a packaged application so I don't really have access to any code or know how the code was developed.

What I am trying to find out is what the JDBC fetchSize is being set to.  I don't know where it is being set, meaning at the ResultSet level or Statement level etc..

Here is what I have tried so far:

1) I tried to configure tracing for the JDBC driver by downloading the ojdbc_g.jar file from Oracle and following the instructions that they provided.  Unfortunately, in those instructions, it states that I need to add this jar file to the CLASSPATH and I am not sure where that is being set in this application.  Needless to say, this path was not fruitful, as I was never able to successfully get a trace file output.

2)  I tried using WireShark to capture all TNS packets to see if I could find it out that way, and this again was fruitless because at that level, it is next to impossible to actually find how many rows are being passed each time.  There are so many other dependencies there, and I was unable to get the info I am after.

3)  The last thing I tried was configuring a database side trace of SQL Net calls to the database, but I am not sure whether I have to do this in the sqlnet.ora file or if I have to trace the listener.

This is where I am stuck now.  Again, all I want to do is find out what the application's JDBC fetchSize is being set (if its even being set at all).  I know that this can impact the performance of the application so that's why I want to find it.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unpack the jar file, try grepping for fetchSize in the class files, this will give you the class file. Then disassemble or decompile, or debug to see what it is set to.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This is a very big application.  There are multiple (like hundreds) of JAR files.  All the connections are being made to the database from a JDBC connection pool.  I wouldn't know which one JAR to unpack.

Comment: use a shell script to unpack all of them and grep all of them. let the computer work for you.

Comment: also if the jars are uncompressed jars, you might even grep the jars themselves. the string might still be visible.

Comment: I ended up having to do exactly what you suggested.  I was hoping to avoid it because there are literally thousands and thousands of class files, but I stumbled up some jars labeled persistence and I unpacked those and decompiled them to see what was being set.  Thanks for the help Markus!